# In Swift, what's the difference between type Int {get set} and Type Int?

Tags: swift

For example:

```
    var someData:Int {
    get {
        return 5
    }

    set {

    }
}

    lazy var data2 = {return 5}()

    var data = 5
```

In the code above, someData and data2 are inferred as Int { get set } and data is inferred as Int.

By the way, was data2 declared from the returned value of a closure? It something like {}() called a closure? I thought closure is something like

```
{
... in

    return ...
}
```

Comment: `{return 5}()` is the same that `{ _ in return 5 }` that is the same that `{ _ ->Int in return 5 }`.

Comment: The same way, `var data = 5` is exactly the same that `var data: Int = 5`. It just let the compiler infer the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ ... }` with appended `()` is just a closure that is immediately being called. It could also be

```
let data2 = { ... in
    return ...
}()
```

`data2` is not inferred as `get set`. `get` and `set` denote a computed property while `data2` is a stored property.

Comment: I notice you can override a stored property with a `{get set}` ..,

Comment: @Grimxn Yes, you can but not the other way around :)

Comment: indeed, but I was surprised that I could even do it one way!

Comment: @Grimxn Stored property just gives you a memory slot to store your data. In an override you can decide to ignore this slot and compute the value dynamically. It's not surprising if you think about it.